# Angular Same Component different routes. dont reload

Tags: angular, angular-routing, angular-router

I have the following routes configured in my app-routing file. Im trying to make the homepage and the contact form both load from the same component. this works but the homeComponent is refreshing when moving between them.

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: HomeComponent,
    data: { contact: false },
  },
  {
    path: 'contact',
    component: HomeComponent,
    data: { contact: true },
  },
];
```

What config would allow me to use the same component that does not reload. The only difference would be `data`

```
Angular CLI: 13.3.11
Node: 16.19.1
Package Manager: npm 8.19.3
OS: darwin arm64

Angular: 13.2.5
... animations, cdk, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms
... language-service, material, platform-browser
... platform-browser-dynamic, platform-server, router
... service-worker

Package                         Version
---------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect       0.1302.5
@angular-devkit/build-angular   13.2.5
@angular-devkit/core            13.2.5
@angular-devkit/schematics      13.3.11
@angular/cli                    13.3.11
@angular/fire                   7.5.0
@angular/google-maps            13.3.9
@angular/pwa                    13.3.11
@nguniversal/express-engine     13.1.1
@schematics/angular             13.3.11
ng-packagr                      13.2.1
rxjs                            6.6.7
typescript                      4.5.5
```